# After disabling MSI modules in magento2.4.1

Tags: inventory, magento2.4.1, msi, salable

My Magento store is throwing this error:

Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\IsProductSalableInterface

I am using Magento 2.4.1

Comment: Have you run all the commands again like deploy, upgrade etc?

Comment: Yes, I run all the commands.